# Azure VM (ARM) external port not working

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to open port 8080 in a Windows Azure virtual machine. I have a test website listening in that port, and I am able to access it via localhost, so the website is running.

I have also opened the port in the firewall and created an inbound security rule in azure portal for the virtual machine, but the port doesn't seem to be open to the outside world. I have tried accessing it both via the IP address and the DNS with the same results.

[image]
[image]

Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: You have only the inbound rule opened, so how do you know the port is not opened? Through the log of you web?

Comment: I tried doing the telnet for the port and also tried browsing the web page. While port 80 works, 8080 does not.

Comment: Seems like a similar issue here, with suggestion you could try: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36413873/2401021